# Angular Forms- FormArray: Cannot find control with path: 'strains -> i'

Tags: angular

I want to create form with a form array. But I get the failure

```
Cannot find control with path: 'strains -> i'
```

But my `strainsForm`contains `strains`.

## MODULE (TS)

```
  strainForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    daysToHarvest: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  })
  strainsForm = new FormGroup({
    strains: new FormArray([this.strainForm])
  })
```

### VIEW (HTML)

```
<form [formGroup]="strainsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<section class="strains container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h3>Strains</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 light-green">
      <fieldset class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 light-green" formArrayName="strains">
        <!--<article class="strain" *ngFor="let strain of chamber.strains; let index = index" formArrayName="strains">-->
        <article class="strain" *ngFor="let strain of chamber.strains; let i = index" formGroupName="i">
```

The examples I found all use the Formbuilder:

- https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
- https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/basics-reactive-forms-in-angular/
- https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

But don't show how define a form with a `formArray`. Or is the FormBuilder required to do this?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Comment: Hi, they also use formBuilder, so is it just possible with formBuilder (and not with the syntax `new FormArray()`?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved by changing `formGroupName` to `[formGroupName]` (with parenthesis)